# from django.urls import path ImportError: cannot import name path

Tags: python, html, django, django-urls, python-django-storages

*When i run* 
**python manage.py migrate** 
*this is what coming and iam not able to fix it please help me* image:

[image]

Comment: Whats the version of django ?

Comment: my django version is : 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed everything correctly.

And could you please try:

```
pip install django-urls
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is must likely a problem with your Django version, `path` was introduced in [version 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.0/#what-s-new-in-django-2-0)

Comment: my django version is : 2.2.6